# Google Forms Upload File - using/modifying the response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

Within a larger process (not relevant here) I would like to use the native Google Forms "File Upload" Question in a form.

I have been trying to understand how to use the response to :

1. rename the file uploaded
2. move/copy/save the file to a specific location 
   (this will be in the end determined by another response item, but for the moment, lets just call it "myDesitinationFolder"

I can of course, in the responses, in the Google interface, or in a Spreadsheet, see the files (and from the spreadsheet, the URL to the file)

but I would like to do my processing before the file is "saved to Drive" or in any case, during the onFormSubmit()

All i find though is a value [randomalphanumeric] and I am unable to find the documentation that explains what this [element] is. (if it is an object - but the square [] would seems to say this is NOT the case) 
(Updated after clarification)

the sample code used to get the value comes from Stack.

```
    .
fonction onFormSubmit(e){ 
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
var formResponse = formResponses[i];
var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
  var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
  Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
             (i + 1).toString(),
             itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
             itemResponse.getResponse());

  console.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
              (i + 1).toString(),
              itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
              itemResponse.getResponse());

   }
 }

}
```

OUTPUT :
Response #19 to the question "fileUpload" was "[1OQeNOTREALCODE5SoAaPiw4s2M-cfRDJ]"

(NOTREALCODE added by me to anonymise response)

my Question : is that a file object? can i access the "save" process to change the destination and the name before hand?
or would my best option be to do a post submit process on an updated sheet (where i have the file URL etc..) (I really dont want to go that way, I would prefer to have it all within the form (I don't need the sheet otherwise)

thanks

Comment: FormSubmit is triggered after the form submit. `1OQeNOTREALCODE5SoAaPiw4s2M-cfRDJ` is probably the fileID of the uploaded file document. You can use this to access/move/modify the file uploaded using `DriveApp`

Comment: thanks. yes, it is the fileID; I have been able to confirm that. so the file is already written to disk. I have to do a move and a rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a file upload form is submitted, Google Form response stores the ID of the file in Google Drive. You can use the DriveApp service to access the uploaded file by ID and rename it, move it or copy to another folder.

```
function renameFile(id) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  file.setName("Some name here");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. yes, this should do what I need!